# How to add props to Vue component programatically?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm using [ag-grid for vue](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-vuejs-data-grid/), and in order to create a custom cell template, you need to define a Vue component and set it as the template, so this is how I define the column:

```
{
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name",
    template: NameLinkCell
},
```

And ag-grid injects into `NameLinkCell`, the params property for you to use:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex center-v">
    <router-link :to="{name:'policy',params:{id: id}}">{{name}}</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import router from "@/router";
export default Vue.extend({
  router,
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.params.data ? this.params.data.id : "-1";
    },
    name() {
      return this.params.data ? this.params.data.name : "";
    }
  }

});
</script>
```

I would like to create a generic component so I need this part to be dynamic:

```
:to="{name:'policy'
```

The problem is it is a metadata prop and not part of the params object passed to the component, how can I pass this extra property?

Comment: Where does the extra property come from? You know you can just pass an object from `data` or `computed` to the `:to` prop right?

Comment: I'd like to use the same `NameLinkCell` component on multiple pages, so obviously it should point to a different route each time, the data does not contain the to property nor should it, as it is metadata. how would using a computed help me if I don't have the `to` property?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that it is not clear for me what you are trying to do. That could easily be my lack of experience with ag-grid. Good luck with getting an answer.